# How to change the numbers to images on JQUERY image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to implement this image slider on my website: http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/ but instead of the content numbers at the bottom being numbers, i would like them to be smaller versions of the images in the slider.

Any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: you need to modify jquery where showcase-navigation-button is added and add small image url

Comment: it wouldn't be better choose this as starting point http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/index4.html is more similar to want u gain- if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you download their JS file and navigate to line #472, you can see that if 'btn_numbers' property is true, they use numeric numbers, but if it's false, they convert it to '●' which is like a small black circle. So, to use images for numbers, create an image for each number, and place an

```
img_name = parseInt(i+1)+".jpg";
<img src=img_name+".jpg">
```

instead of the numeric counter. Obviously, the code above won't execute straightaway, but it's a starting point and since the entire code is in a loop, it'll pick an image for each number that you've created.

Comment: Good for you, please accept this as the solution as this helps the community too.